# Partial View with different ViewModel than Parent's ViewModel

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my `View` I'm displaying a dropdown for selecting a list of years. But the data corresponding to selected year comes from more than one tables. And hence a `Partial View`'s data corresponding to selected year needs a `ViewModal`. The data in partial view is a list of records from the ViewModel. **Question**: How can above be achieved while we are dealing with two different ViewModels in a same View. Example follows:

**Note**:

1. I'm using Ajax and [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro). But any suggestions without these technologies would be fine.
2. I'm aware of how to load Partial View data via Ajax.

**Parent's ViewModel** [for Years dropdown]

```
public class OrderYearsViewModel
{
  public SelectList lstOrderYears { get; set; }    
  public int SelectedOrdYear { get; set; }
}
```

**Parent View**

```
@model MyProj.Models.OrderYearsViewModel

<div>
  <form asp-controller="OrderYearsCtrl" asp-action="SelectYearsList" method="get">
    Select Order Year:<select asp-for="SelectedOrdYear" asp-items="Model.lstOrderYears"></select><button type="button" value="Go" class="clsGo">GO</button>
  </form>
</div
<div id="OrderDetailsID">
  <!--Partial view data for selected year displayed here-->
</div>
```

**Partial View's ViewModel** [for Orders selected per year]

```
public class OrdersPerYearViewModel
{
  public in CustomerID { get; set; }    
  public string CustName{ get; set; }
  public string OrderType { get; set; }
  public float Price { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model List<MyProj.Models.OrdersPerYearViewModel>
<table><tr><th>..</th>..........</th></tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.CustomerID
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.CustName
        </td>
        <td>
           @item.OrderType
        </td>
        <td>
           @item.Price 
        </td>
        ....
}
</table>
```

Comment: So you need to load partial when the dropdown changed right ?

Comment: @Krishna Exactly..

Comment: Then use jQuery to call the partial view on dropdown change

Comment: Or on go button click

Comment: @Krishna How would I do that - can you demo a brief sample - just for illustration purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just make an Ajax call

```
@model MyProj.Models.OrderYearsViewModel
<div>
  Select Order Year:<select id="ddlYear" asp-for="SelectedOrdYear" asp-items="Model.lstOrderYears"></select><button id="btnGo" type="button" value="Go" class="clsGo">GO</button>
</div>
<div id="OrderDetailsID">
  <!--Related data for each year displayed here-->
</div>
```

On document ready register button click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnGo").click(function(){$("#OrderDetailsID").load("@Url.Action("yourpartialviewactionname","controllername")"+"?year="+$("#ddlYear").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: But in your example also the partial view requires a different `vievModel` than parent's viewModel. Is it something different than loading partial view via `Ajax`?

Comment: Loading view from Ajax will not make full page post back

Comment: In my example you don't need to pass view model to partial view you just pass the selected year from parent

Comment: @ Krishna. You do need the second viewModel for partial view since partial view is using different attributes than just selected year. Moreover, Partial view's data displays a list of records so we cannot combine the two `ViewModels` here as well. Otherwise, I generally add the attributes of first ViwModel into the second and it works. But not here.

Comment: True, but what's exactly your point ? You don't want to use another view model ?

Comment: @nam Your main view has the years. 1. User selects the year and presses GO. 2. You send the year to your controller as Krishna has shown. 3. Your controller takes the year and prepares a model for your partial view and sends it to the partial view. 4. Your partial view is generated. 5. Your return the partial view and ajax will bring it to the parent view. 6. The `load` method will take the partial view and inject it into the parent view. Makes sense?

Comment: @Krishna I thought viewmodels have to be same for parent and it's partial. So, in that case I'm looking for a workaround or a better approach for my case.

Comment: In can do that by placing list<order> in parent

Comment: @CodingYoshi Uhm!!!. Let me try. I thought Parent and it's partial have to have same ViewModels since at the end its just one page and hence it will complain if two different viewmodels are used.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Your just one comment explaining suggested solution step by step made so much sense - and it worked. Although that was my original intent but I thought two different ViewModels won't fit here - but it seems in case of a partial View parent and its partial view can have different `ViewModels`.